# Does `input()` Python function has the characters like GNU read?

Tags: python

GNU read has `-n` options and that can set the character that will read, from document:

> `-n nchars`
>
> read returns after reading nchars characters rather
>
> than waiting for a complete line of input.

`read -n 1` will only read one character and quit.

But `input()` will read the input until user type <kbd>Enter</kbd> (like `read` without `-n` option does).

And I didn't find any option of `input()` . Does `input()` support this or Python has other function can do this?

Comment: `input()` can't do this - you might want to take a look at [the `curses` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/curses.html) in the standard library, which supports more advanced input at the console.

Comment: @Latty Let me see that :)